# Subprocess call with exit status 128

Tags: python, git, subprocess

Essentially, I am trying to use a subprocess call to checkout a git commit at a specific sha hash.

However, I keep getting the error `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'checkout', '62bbce43e']' returned non-zero exit status 128.`

This is my code below:

```
with open(filename) as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=",")
    linecount = 0
    for row in reader:
        if linecount == 0:
            linecount += 1
        else:
            repo = str(row[0])
            sha = str(row[2])
            specificfile = str(row[3])
            linenum = int(row[4])
            cl("cd", repo)
            subprocess.check_output(['git', 'checkout', sha])
            print("checkout done")
            git("checkout", "-")
```

Comment: `check_output` raises `CalledProcessError` if the status isn't 0, but you can still catch that error and handle things properly.  Probably the stdout of git checkout ( possibly easiest to obtain by running it by hand in a shell) will explain what scenario corresponds with that 128 exit code - I couldn't find one in the manpag for git-checkout.

Comment: Paulo, rather than edit your question to say an answer fixed the problem, just accept the answer (that big honkin' green tick mark next to it). That way, the Q&A nature of SO works as expected (helping people in future as well).

Comment: Ah thank you! Have done it. Sorry, new to actually posting on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `subprocess.check_output()` call actually returns the output (and you can also get error output as well by passing a `stderr` parameter). You may want to have a look at that to see if it gives you an error explaining what happened.

Since you're getting an exception (meaning the call is not completing hence output may not be returned), you should be able to get the output from one of the exception members:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'checkout', sha], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("Exception on process, rc=", e.returncode, "output=", e.output)
```

---

One thing I *do* know is that some `git` commands tend to return 128 if you're not actually *in* a Git repo. So I'd be looking at the path following your `cl("cd", repo)` line, with:

```
os.system("pwd")  # use "cd" for Windows.
```

If that `cd` of yours is running in a *sub-process,* that will *not* affect the current process and therefore you may not necessarily be in a Git repo at all. That would certainly explain the `128` return code.

By way of example, the following transcript shows what happens when I try to run a `git` command outside of a repo:

```
>>> try:
...     output = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'checkout', '12345'])
... except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
...     print(e.returncode, e.output)
...

128 b'fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git\n'
```

If it turns out you *are* in the wrong directory (i.e., the `cl("cd", repo)` statement is running a sub-process to change directory), you should use the Python-blessed method to change directories <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```

That actually changes the directory for the *immediate* process (the Python interpreter) rather than a transient sub-process.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is actually good advice in general - use Python-specific stuff as much as possible (since it's mostly cross-platform) rather than spawning a sub-shell (which is inherently platform-specific).

Comment: `output` is going to be `stdout` but not `stderr` which is likely to have the error message.  Either way, this isn't going to affect whether the exception is raised.

Comment: @DanielFarrell, I have little interest in *handling* the exception yet, the intent is to find out *why* the exception is happening.

Comment: I was assuming that 128 meant something that would have to be handled in normal program flow you make a good point about the `cd` so hopefully OP won't have to deal with nonzero exit code.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it does seem it is a problem that I am not actually changing into the repository. How would I go about this? My call was essentially `subprocess.call(['cd', '(name of repository)'])` but when I run `os.system("pwd")`, it is only printing out my current directory path.
Edit: Was able to use os.chdir() for this.

Comment: @paulo: I've updated the answer to include this (among a lot of other stuff), hopefully that will help.

Comment: I get the `128` because of `fatal: No configured push destination`. I am in a git repo and the helping `fatal` message with the missing `remote` is some lines above, so I have to scroll up. Solution: `git remote add..` helps here

Answer (score 4):

For me, running the program from `inside the git repo` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the other point—that causing one sub-shell commands to `chdir` to some other directory does not affect subsequent separate sub-shell or sub-process commands, while calling `os.chdir` directly affects *your* process and therefore affects its subprocesses—note that you have two additional options here:

- The `subprocess` functions all accept a keyword `cwd` argument, whose default is `cwd=None`.  Providing a string here causes Python to `os.chdir` into the specified directory just for that one subprocess call.

  See the details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).
- Git itself provides a flag, `-C`, that tells Git to do its own `chdir` early on.  To invoke `git checkout` as if it were `cd path/to/repo; git checkout`, use `git -C path/to/repo checkout`.

  This flag was new in Git version 1.8.5, so if your Git is older than that, you won't have `git -C` (but if your Git is older than 2.x it's long past time to upgrade :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that `git clone` was being called but that the library that I was cloning already existed. So the tool I was using was calling

```bash
git clone https://somevendor.org/my-repo
```

but `my-repo` was already a non-empty directory that existed. Deleting the existing folder solved the issue.