# Call git command with hook on a different directory?

Tags: python, git

I have 2 repos on my server, one is a bare repo and the other one is a "real/non-bare" repo with worktree.
Inside my bare repo I have a post-receive hook that should change directory to the real/non-bare repo and call a git command:

```
git pull origin master
```

So that my real repo is updated according to the pushes made on the bare repository.
But I get an error:

```
remote: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'pull', 'origin', 'master']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

It seems to me that although I changed the os.chdir() to the real repo inside hook script,
git ignored that and it does not recognize my git repo.

When I run the hook directly by going to the bare repo hook directory and run **python3 post-receive** it does run the
command without throwing an error.

Git dir is the bare repo
Git_real is the non-bare repo

```
home/my_machine
├── Git
│   └── search_movie.git
│       ├── branches
│       ├── config
│       ├── description
│       ├── HEAD
│       ├── hooks
│       │   └── post-receive   
│       ├── info
│       │   └── exclude
│       ├── objects
│       │   ├── 93
│       │   │   └── 68286a3e6b37235950d0b369d6aa955bc6699b
│       │   ├── info
│       │   └── pack
│       │       ├── pack-8710cd10d53b27cda2228c33ff59e337426563b9.idx
│       │       └── pack-8710cd10d53b27cda2228c33ff59e337426563b9.pack
│       └── refs
│           ├── heads
│           │   └── master
│           └── tags
└── Git_real
    └── search_movie
        ├── find_movie.py
        ├── output.txt
        └── search_vid.py
```

post-receive hook

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, os, subprocess
path_2_non_bare_repo = "/home/my_machine/Git_real/search_movie" 
#cwd is the path to my_repo/.git/hooks
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

#change dir to real repository
os.chdir(path_2_non_bare_repo)
try:
    pll = subprocess.check_output(["git", "pull", "origin", "master"], shell=False)
    print("fetch =", pll)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    print(err)
```

The Q is why is git not recognizing my current working directory change made with os.chdir?

Comment: Have you tried passing `cwd=path_2_non_bare_repo` to `subprocess.check_output` (instead of using `os.chdir(...)`)? It's an optional argument https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Comment: Yes I did but same error

Comment: See if any of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575970/subprocess-call-with-exit-status-128 help

Comment: Not even this solved the problem: **subprocess.check_output(["git", "pull", "origin", "master"],cwd=path_2_non_bare_repo, shell=False, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git hooks run with numerous Git-specific environment variables set so that references to *some* Git repository will go to *this* Git repository, where
"this" means "the one running the hook".

The result is that if you:

```
cd /path/to/other/repo
```

and then run some Git command, the Git command you've run operates in the original repository, not the `/path/to/other/repo` repository.

To fix this, you must *un*-set the appropriate Git-specific environment variables.  These include, but are not necessarily limited to, `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`.  The one that is definitely set and definitely *must* be unset is `GIT_DIR`.

Comment: How would I change those variables in my hook script? Are those variables defined in the .git/config?

Comment: Those are *environment* variables. If you use a shell script, you use `unset` to unset an an environment variable. In Python, when you use `subprocess`, you have an `env` dictionary you can pass: you make a copy of the incoming environment, then change or remove the copy and pass that as the outgoing environment. The details vary depending on what language you use to write your hooks, in other words.

Comment: Thank you that did work. I unset the enviro variable. I thought there are special git environment variables but you meant the shell's.

Answer (score 1):

Check your error message -- meaning : choose a way to inspect your process' stderr when it errors.

---

`git` exiting with a `128` exit code does not specifically indicate "not run from within a repository".

For example : `git fetch origin nonexistingbranch` exits with code `128`